# How to add columns to pandas dataframe for class object in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I want to create a class object to deal with my dataset automatically

For example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
class newdata(object):
    def __init__(self,dataset):
        self.a = dataset.a
        self.b = dataset.b
        self.dataset = dataset
    def add_column(self,c):
        self[c] = a
newdata(x).add_column("c")
```

however, I get an error:

```
'newdata' object does not support item assignment
```

What's more, when I change the formula, I get a new error

```
    def add_column(self,c):
        self[c] = a + 3

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Cycle' and 'int'
```

If I write the code out of class, it works

```
x['c'] = x.a
x['c'] = x.a +3
```

why it doesn't work in the class object?

Comment: `self.dataset[c] = self.a`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to assign attributes like this: `self[c] = a + 3`.
I could not reproduce the TypeError, but to use the `a` attribute from `newdata()` you have to write `self.a`, otherwise `a` will not be defined.
There are different ways to assing an attribute to an instance, one of them is `setattr()`

```
def add_column(self, attr_name):
    setattr(self, attr_name, self.a + 3)
```

To add `c` as an attribute to the class instance you would do it like that:

```
inst = newdata(x)
inst.add_column('c')
```

`newdata(x).add_column('c')` however still doesn't append your Dataframe with `c`. One workaround you could use instead is:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7,8,9]})

class newdata:
    def __init__(self, df) -> None:
        self.__dict__ = df.to_dict('series')

    def add_column(self, df):
        self.__dict__.update(df.to_dict('series'))
        return pd.DataFrame(self.__dict__)

df = newdata(x).add_column(y)
```